# Histogram and correlation with 5 variables

Tags: r, histogram, correlation

I am new in R and I had made some graphs with small dataset. Now I want to plot (histogram and correlation) in a dataset with 9 variables and 107 observations.

its about deaths per 100.000 people caused by lung cancer. I have five columns with numbers of deaths per 100.000, one for a range of age(0-14 years, 15-44, 45-54, 55-64, 65+) In the rows there are the states of the country. I have done this with no success:

```
hist(PULMON.R$X0.14.años, PULMON.R$X15.44.años, PULMON.R$X45.54.años, PULMON.R$X55.64.años, PULMON.R$X65.Y.MAS.años)
Error in hist.default(PULMON.R$X0.14.años, PULMON.R$X15.44.años, PULMON.R$X45.54.años,  : 
  'probability' is an alias for '!freq', however they differ.
```

And I get a strange graphic with several numbers in axis X doing this:

```
barplot(PULMON.R$X0.14.años, PULMON.R$X15.44.años, PULMON.R$X45.54.años, PULMON.R$X55.64.años, PULMON.R$X65.Y.MAS.años)
```

And for the correlation I get nothing. I want to see if there is a relation between age (getting older) with more death cases. I have done this:

```
cor(PULMON.R$X0.14.años, PULMON.R$X15.44.años, PULMON.R$X45.54.años, PULMON.R$X55.64.años, PULMON.R$X65.Y.MAS.años)
Error in cor(PULMON.R$X0.14.años, PULMON.R$X15.44.años, PULMON.R$X45.54.años,  : 
  unused argument (PULMON.R$X65.Y.MAS.años)
```

My dataset is PULMON.R  Pulmon means lung in Spanish.

Comment: add a reproducible example (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) so SO can help you

Comment: It will be easier to show you how to fix these problems if you provide a sample of your data. Please add to your question the output of `dput(PULMON.R[1:10,])`.

Comment: I think you want `cor(PULMON.R[,c("X0.14.años","X15.44.años","X45.54.años",etc)]) `

Answer (score 1):

That's not how any of these functions work. You can't simply pass a large number of vectors to each. Take a look at the help files for each function (`? hist`, `? barplot`, `? cor`) to see what is possible.

- `cor()` expects a matrix as its first argument
- `hist()` expects a single vector as its first argument
- `barplot()` expects a vector of heights (not a raw vector) as its first argument

So your `cor()` line can be:

```
cor(cbind(PULMON.R$X0.14.años, PULMON.R$X15.44.años, PULMON.R$X45.54.años, PULMON.R$X55.64.años, PULMON.R$X65.Y.MAS.años))
```

But the others will need to be separate plots, which you can create in a loop:

```
layout(matrix(1:5, nrow = 1))
lapply(PULMON.R[, c("X0.14.años", "X15.44.años", "X45.54.años", "X55.64.años", "X65.Y.MAS.años")], hist)
```